# Cronjob in every 5 minutes until 17.00 pm Cpanel

Tags: linux, cron, cpanel

```
Minute  Hour    Day Month   Weekday
*/5 *   *   *   *
```

This code triggers page in every 5 minutes **for 24 hours**. But i want it **until 17.00 pm** (or any hour). how can i change it in **Cpanel**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the range specification:

```
*/5 0-17 * * *
```

You didn't give a starting time, so I assumed midnight (0).  Adjust to taste.

Comment: Thank you Jim. it is so simply.